# Why do certain C programs use an arrow operator to point to parts of a structure instead of directly referencing?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, winsock2

I was working on a winsock2 program, and one line of code on MSDN caught my eye:

```
ConnectSocket=socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
```

Why is a pointer used to reference the structure instead of directly referencing the structure with the dot operator?

EDIT: see the code here: [Creating a Socket for the Client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530741.aspx)

Comment: Because `ptr` is a pointer, if you want to know why `ptr` is a pointer, can you  post all the usages of `ptr`?

Comment: In other words, to access the members of a structure pointed to by `p`, you use the `arrow` operator (e.g. `p->member`). To access members of `struct p` itself, you use the `dot` operator (e.g. `p.member`).

Comment: How do you propose to *directly* use the dot operator when `ptr` is a pointer???

Comment: @AnT: you have to dereference the pointer first (`(*p)->member`).  The `->` operator combines the `*` and `.` operators.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Firstly, that would be `(*ptr).member`. Secondly, this is not a *direct* application of `.` operator to `ptr`. Using it *directly* with `ptr` is impossible. One has to use `*` first. Thirdly, if the OP realized that, they'd immediately see that the `.`-based approach is much more convoluted (requires `*` and `()`), which would make the value of `->` obvious.

Comment: And if you have nested structures, it is easier to read (and write!) `ptr->ptr_member->member` than it is to read `(*(*ptr).ptr_member).member` — if I got that right.  Of course, the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) argues against such chains of references, but they do occur (and sometimes more than just two levels of nesting deep).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C/C++, the `->` operator is used to access the props and functions of an object that a pointer is pointing at (ie. `myClass->propOne`). Keeping in mind that a pointer is just a reference to memory, you can see that it would not have `propOne` since it is just a memory location. The `->` operator says that you want to access `propOne` of the object located in the memory that `myClass` is pointing at.

You could also achieve this by dereferencing the pointer with the `*` operator to access the object, and then use the `.` operator to access the prop (ie. `(*myClass).propOne`).

They are both valid, but the `->` is a bit cleaner, and can lead to fewer coding errors.

Addressing the *why* question, there are a lot of reasons to use pointers. Sometimes you want to pass around a value or a structure but you do not want to copy it. Sometimes you may want more than one thing to be able to access the same structure easily. Sometimes it is just easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` operator is used to access members of an object when you are operating on

1. **the object directly**:

   ```
   Type obj;
   obj.member
   ```
2. **a reference to the object**:

   ```
   Type obj;
   Type &ref = obj;
   ref.member
   ```

The `->` operator is used to access members of an object when you are operating on **a pointer to the object** instead:

```
Type obj;
Type *ptr = &obj;
ptr->member
```

The `->` operator is just a cleaner way of using the `*` and `.` operators together:

```
Type obj;
Type *ptr = &obj;
(*ptr).member
```

In this case, since `ptr` is a pointer, you can use either `->` or `*.` to access its members.

In the linked example, the reason `ptr` is a pointer is because the code is using [`getaddrinfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520.aspx), which returns a dynamically allocated linked-list of [`addrinfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737530.aspx) structures, where `ptr` is a pointer to a particular item in the list.

The MSDN example only accesses the first item in the list, but it is customary to loop through the entire list, as `getaddrinfo()` can return multiple addresses.  You need to use a pointer to loop through the list, eg:

```
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;
    int iResult;
    WSADATA wsa;

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsa);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // allows IPv4 and IPv6 addresses
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to each address returned by
    // the call to getaddrinfo until one succeeds
    for(ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next)
    {
        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            continue;
        }

        // connect to server
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == 0) {
            printf("Connected!\n");
            break;
        }

        printf("Unable to connect: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());

        // Destroy the SOCKET before trying the next address
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket != INVALID_SOCKET) {
        // use ConnectSocket as needed...
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    }

    WSACleaup();
    return 0;
}
```